# Creating function to write excel sheets using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
def CTDataSQ (name):
    name= cleanDF[["PatientstudyId2","RATER","CT_3D",name]]
    name= name.loc[name['CT_3D'] == 1]
    del name["CT_3D"]
    name.to_excel(name, ".xlsx") 
    
    
for y in Questions:
    CTDataSQ(y)
```

I'm attempting to create a function that creates excel spreadsheet outputs with names derived from a list. I get the following error.

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Looked online and cannot seem to solve. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as indicated in the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), the `to_excel` method have a first parameter that accepts a `str` or an ExcelWriter object. In your case I assume you're trying to pass a `str`. In this case, it is not possible to pass `name` as the parameter because it is not a `str`, it is a `pandas.DataFrame` since there is:

```
name = name.loc[name['CT_3D'] == 1]
```

I suppose you're trying to pass a column name (str), filter by another one (CT_3D), assign it to a new final df and save it. I'd do the following for that:

```
def CTDataSQ (col_name):
    final_df= cleanDF[["PatientstudyId2","RATER","CT_3D",col_name]]
    final_df= final_df.loc[final_df['CT_3D'] == 1]
    del final_df["CT_3D"]
    final_df.to_excel(col_name + ".xlsx") 
    
    
for y in Questions:
    CTDataSQ(y)
```

This way, it is better diferentiated the column name from the dataframe. And as you can see, you have to concatenate the strings col_name with the extension (.xlsx) with a `+` sign, not separate them by a comma (since it is considered as another parameter for .to_excel).